# iOS: Calling URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier: in Background mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icloud

I am trying to update an iCloud file. So, when the application enters the background mode, I start syncing this file. However, as I check for iCloud availability as shown below, I got no response.

Here is the code I use:

```
    dispatch_queue_t q_default;
    q_default = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(q_default, ^{
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];;
        NSLog(@"step 1");
        if ([fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil] != nil) {
            NSLog(@"step 2");
            [self copyDatabaseToTempDirectory];

            if (![self copyDatabaseToTempDirectory]) {
                return;
            }

            [self moveDatabaseFromTempDirectoryToTheCloud];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"iCloud Not Available");
            self.Sync_POST = NO;

        }

    });
    NSLog(@"step 3");
```

The following is the log:
step 3
step 1